# How do i make each thread use the next useragent line by line from my txt file

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

How do I make each thread use the next user agent line by line from my txt file

I usually get an error when i try to import my user agents to firefox profile

''''

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
import threading
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile




    with open("useragents.txt", "r") as file:
        user_agent = file.read()
        print(user_agent)

    ff_profile = FirefoxProfile()
    ff_profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override",
                              user_agent)

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile = ff_profile)
    driver.get('https://www.whatsmyua.info/')







N = 5   # Number of browsers to spawn
thread_list = list()

# Start test
for i in range(N):
t = threading.Thread(name='Test {}'.format(i))
t.start()
time.sleep(3)
print ("t.name + ' started!'")
thread_list.append(t)

 # Wait for all thre<ads to complete
 for thread in thread_list:
 thread.join()
```

''''

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it, try

```
with open("user_agent.txt", "r") as file:
    user_agent = file.read()
    print(user_agent)

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user_agent)
# add profile to webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: i got an error              selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Failed to set preferences: Unable to read profile preferences file

Comment: when i tried this other method , my useragent did not change                                                                                                
f = open('useragent.txt', 'r')
list_of_lines = f.read().splitlines()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference('general.useragent.override', list_of_lines)
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.ipchicken.com/')

Comment: @MichaelCyber try the updated code in my answer, make sure to update file name

Comment: thanks but only the first useragent is in the txt file is used in all the threading

Answer (score 0):

got it to work using this code

''''

```
with open('useragents.txt', 'r') as f:
  for line in f:

    print(line)
```

''''